# Unicode characters xn--ls8h

Tags: unicode, character, representation, emoji

I want to know how to write the unicode Emoji characters in this form "xn--ls8h" <-- that is the pile of poo emoji unicode character. I had never seen this form, always something like &#5623*; (no asterisk) or something like that... What is this "xn--" form and how do I convert to it? Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xn--` is the prefix used in the ASCII representation of an [Internationalized Domain Name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name), and `ls8h` is the [Punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) representation of the character.

In Python, Punycode is one of the standard character encodings:

```
>>> b'ls8h'.decode('punycode')
'\U0001f4a9'
```

Comment: Awesome, the domain thing makes sense now because I was going to http://www.xn--ls8h.la which becomes an emoji charter domain name.